# Версия composer

Tags: composer

Всем привет. Не кидайте тряпками. Необходимо обновить зависимости в проекте. Делаю `composer update` и получаю:

```
wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin v1.4.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint
```

На сколько я понимаю для данного пакета необходим composer-plugin-api от версии 1.0 и выше, но у меня 2.0.0. Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Было нужно установить 1-ю версию composer. Для это нужно выполнить команду:

```
composer self-update --1
```

Для возвращения ко второй версии:

```
composer self-update --2
```

или:

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

Источник: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597051/how-to-downgrade-or-install-a-specific-version-of-composer-on-windows)